# Replacement for GetItemWithInterfaces in GlassMapper latest

Tags: glass-mapper

We are currently on GlassMapper 4.5 and looking to upgrade to the latest version of GlassMapper. We have a couple of spots where we are using GetItemWithInterfaces. This method no longer exists and I can't find a replacement. Has anyone using this method upgraded and how did you handle this?